# Object loses data when PutParcable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I created a user class and I initialize it like so:

```
User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
```

I then populated the object with the user data and to pass it to another activity I do it like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyActivity));
Bundle bundlee = new Bundle();
bundlee.PutParcelable("MyUser", MyUser); // Persist user class to next activity
intent.PutExtra("TheBundle", bundlee);
StartActivity(intent);
```

I then retrieve the user data in the other activity like so:

```
// I initialize a variable again
User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
MyUser = bundlee.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;
```

I get all the data EXCEPT Address, City, and State.  Weird ... I put breakpoints in the code and its all there when I put it in the bundle, but when I take it out those three fields are null strings. My user class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;


using Java.Interop;

using Object = Java.Lang.Object;

namespace MyAndroid
{
    class User : Object, IParcelable
    {
        private string mUsername = "";
        private string mPassword = "";
        private string mFirstname = "";
        private string mMiddleInitial = "";
        private string mLastname = "";
        private string mSuffix = "";
        private string mAddress = "";
        private string mCity = "";
        private string mState = "";
        private string mZip = "";
        private string mZip4 = "";
        private string mHomephone = "";
        private string mCellphone = "";
        private string mWorkphone = "";
        private string mNationalOrgn = "";
        private string mCountry = "";
        private string mCompany = "";
        private string mDepartment = "";
        private string mSection = "";
        private string mProgram = "";
        private string mUsertype = "";
        private string mEmailaddress = "";

        [ExportField("CREATOR")]
        public static UserCreator InitializeCreator()
        {
            return new UserCreator();
        }

        // properties
        public string Username
        {
            get
            {
                return mUsername;
            }
            set
            {
                mUsername = value;
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return mPassword;
            }
            set
            {
                mPassword = value;
            }
        }

        public string Firstname
        {
            get
            {
                return mFirstname;
            }
            set
            {
                mFirstname = value;
            }
        }

        public string MiddleInitial
        {
            get
            {
                return mMiddleInitial;
            }
            set
            {
                mMiddleInitial = value;
            }
        }

        public string Lastname
        {
            get
            {
                return mLastname;
            }
            set
            {
                mLastname = value;
            }
        }

        public string Suffix
        {
            get
            {
                return mSuffix;
            }
            set
            {
                mSuffix = value;
            }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return mAddress;
            }
            set
            {
                mAddress = value;
            }
        }

        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                return mCity;
            }
            set
            {
                mCity = value;
            }
        }

        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return mState;
            }
            set
            {
                mState = value;
            }
        }

        public string Zip
        {
            get
            {
                return mZip;
            }
            set
            {
                mZip = value;
            }
        }

        public string Zip4
        {
            get
            {
                return mZip4;
            }
            set
            {
                mZip4 = value;
            }
        }

        public string Homephone
        {
            get
            {
                return mHomephone;
            }
            set
            {
                mHomephone = value;
            }
        }

        public string Cellphone
        {
            get
            {
                return mCellphone;
            }
            set
            {
                mCellphone = value;
            }
        }

        public string Workphone
        {
            get
            {
                return mWorkphone;
            }
            set
            {
                mWorkphone = value;
            }
        }

        public string NationalOrgn
        {
            get
            {
                return mNationalOrgn;
            }
            set
            {
                mNationalOrgn = value;
            }
        }

        public string Country
        {
            get
            {
                return mCountry;
            }
            set
            {
                mCountry = value;
            }
        }

        public string Company
        {
            get
            {
                return mCompany;
            }
            set
            {
                mACompany = value;
            }
        }

        public string Department
        {
            get
            {
                return mDepartment;
            }
            set
            {
                mDepartment = value;
            }
        }

        public string Section
        {
            get
            {
                return mSection;
            }
            set
            {
                mSection = value;
            }
        }

        public string Program
        {
            get
            {
                return mProgram;
            }
            set
            {
                mProgram = value;
            }
        }

        public string Usertype
        {
            get
            {
                return mUsertype;
            }
            set
            {
                mUsertype = value;
            }
        }

        public string Emailaddress
        {
            get
            {
                return mEmailaddress;
            }
            set
            {
                mEmailaddress = value;
            }
        }

        public int DescribeContents()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public User(string Username, string Password, string Firstname, string MiddleInitial, string Lastname, string Suffix,
            string address, string city, string state, string Zip, string Zip4, string Homephone, string Cellphone, string Workphone, 
            string NationalOrgn, string Country, string Company, string Section, string Department, string Usertype, 
            string Emailaddress)
        {
            this.mUsername = Username;
            this.mPassword = Password;
            this.mFirstname = Firstname;
            this.mMiddleInitial = MiddleInitial;
            this.mLastname = Lastname;
            this.mSuffix = Suffix;
            this.mAddress = Address;
            this.mCity = City;
            this.mState = State;
            this.mZip = Zip;
            this.mZip4 = Zip4;
            this.mHomephone = Homephone;
            this.mCellphone = Cellphone;
            this.mWorkphone = Workphone;
            this.mNationalOrgn = NationalOrgn;
            this.mCountry = Country;
            this.mCompany = Company;
            this.mSection = Section;
            this.mDepartment = Department;
            this.mUsertype = Usertype;
            this.mEmailaddress = Emailaddress;


        }


        public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
        {
            dest.WriteString(this.Username);
            dest.WriteString(this.Password);
            dest.WriteString(this.Firstname);
            dest.WriteString(this.MiddleInitial);
            dest.WriteString(this.Lastname);
            dest.WriteString(this.Suffix);
            dest.WriteString(this.Address);
            dest.WriteString(this.City);
            dest.WriteString(this.State);
            dest.WriteString(this.Zip);
            dest.WriteString(this.Zip4);
            dest.WriteString(this.Homephone);
            dest.WriteString(this.Cellphone);
            dest.WriteString(this.Workphone);
            dest.WriteString(this.NationalOrgn);
            dest.WriteString(this.Country);
            dest.WriteString(this.Company);
            dest.WriteString(this.Section);
            dest.WriteString(this.Department);
            dest.WriteString(this.Usertype);
            dest.WriteString(this.Emailaddress);
        }

    }
    class UserCreator : Object, IParcelableCreator
    {
        public Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            return new User(source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), 
                source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), 
                source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), 
                source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), 
                source.ReadString(), source.ReadString());
        }

        public Object[] NewArray(int size)
        {
            return new Object[size];
        }
    }

}
```

I must be missing something ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got a bit of a naming issue here. Look at this part

```
public User(string Username, string Password, string Firstname, string MiddleInitial, string Lastname, string Suffix,
            string address, string city, string state, string Zip, string Zip4, string Homephone, string Cellphone, string Workphone, 
            string NationalOrgn, string Country, string Company, string Section, string Department, string Usertype, 
            string Emailaddress)
        {
            this.mUsername = Username;
            this.mPassword = Password;
            this.mFirstname = Firstname;
            this.mMiddleInitial = MiddleInitial;
            this.mLastname = Lastname;
            this.mSuffix = Suffix;
            this.mAddress = Address;
            this.mCity = City;
            this.mState = State;
            this.mZip = Zip;
            this.mZip4 = Zip4;
            this.mHomephone = Homephone;
            this.mCellphone = Cellphone;
            this.mWorkphone = Workphone;
            this.mNationalOrgn = NationalOrgn;
            this.mCountry = Country;
            this.mCompany = Company;
            this.mSection = Section;
            this.mDepartment = Department;
            this.mUsertype = Usertype;
            this.mEmailaddress = Emailaddress;
        }
```

Especially this:

```
this.mAddress = Address;
this.mCity = City;
this.mState = State;
```

The correct way would be:

```
this.mAddress = address;
this.mCity = city;
this.mState = state;
```

You are infact not using your parameters (these three at least)! This "error" is kinda mean, because your compiler is not complaining. That's because you actually are assigning your properties (=null) themselves and this is correct but certainly not intended here ;)!

Changing it to the above one should do the trick.

Comment: Lol ... of course ... I figured it was something like that ... I looked and I looked but could not see ... thanks, needed that second set of eyes.